# How, in pytorch, do I set the second gpu as the default within a juptyer notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I have two gpus, and want to open a second juptyer notebook and ensure everything within it runs only on the second gpu rather than the first.  Ideally I'd like to do this by running a cell at the start rather than passing device=1 in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this scenario is to call set device.

```
import torch
torch.cuda.set_device(1)
```

The docs however discourage it.  According to the github note on the checkin (https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/260)  my scenario is the only reasonable use case. The preferred method is to set an environment variable, which is also possible in the notebook case:

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES']='1'
```